# Opera momentum scrolling

Tags: macos, mac, opera

Opera 10.6 for OS X seems to add its own momentum while scrolling, is there a way to disable this?

Answer (score 0):

[This comment](http://my.opera.com/desktopteam/blog/2010/04/16/evenes-mac-final-rc?startidx=50#comment24922882) says you can disable it from opera:config#UserPrefs|SmoothScrolling.